# generate url in smart contract, based on block.chainid and address(this)

Tags: solidity, assembly, string, bytes, function

For the past few days I have been looking into creating a simple function to generate a url based on block.chainid (uint256) and address(this).

The idea is as follows:

```
function url() public view returns (string memory) {
        return string.concat("https://website.com/token/", Strings.toString(block.chainid), "/", Strings.toHexString(address(this)));
    }
```

The above works with the `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";` library, but deployment costs increase by 300K gas.

I have been looking into doing this in assembly by converting everythings to bytes, concating them and converting it into a string. Which in most tries only increase gas by a few thousand, but all attempts failed as I'm very new to assembly.

Anyone knows the propper assambly for this :)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: I will check your solution @MilaA! Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's easier to do that with a few utility conversion functions.

My solution is:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;


contract Test {
    function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
        if (_i == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint j = _i;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
            len++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len;
        while (_i != 0) {
            k = k-1;
            uint8 temp = (48 + uint8(_i - _i / 10 * 10));
            bytes1 b1 = bytes1(temp);
            bstr[k] = b1;
            _i /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }

    function toAsciiString(address x) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory s = new bytes(40);
        for (uint i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            bytes1 b = bytes1(uint8(uint(uint160(x)) / (2**(8*(19 - i)))));
            bytes1 hi = bytes1(uint8(b) / 16);
            bytes1 lo = bytes1(uint8(b) - 16 * uint8(hi));
            s[2*i] = char(hi);
            s[2*i+1] = char(lo);            
        }
        return string(s);
    }

    function char(bytes1 b) internal pure returns (bytes1 c) {
        if (uint8(b) < 10) return bytes1(uint8(b) + 0x30);
        else return bytes1(uint8(b) + 0x57);
    }

    function url() public view returns (string memory) {
        string memory domainString = "https://opensea.io/";
        string memory blockString = uint2str(block.number);
        string memory chainIdString = uint2str(block.chainid);
        string memory addressString = toAsciiString(address(this));


        return string.concat(
                domainString,
                blockString,
                '/',
                chainIdString,
                '/',
                addressString
            );
    }
}
```

It is not so costly, it only costs 8216 gas to deploy the `Test` contract.

**The result from Remix is:**

`https://opensea.io/6/1/7ef2e0048f5baede046f6bf797943daf4ed8cb47`

Comment: Will check it out, thanks!

Comment: Did this work for you? :)

Comment: I don't know on which chain you deployed it, but when I deploy it on testnet of ETH itself its 481982 gas for the deployment costs. Code does work :)

Comment: Aah, good to know!! :)